# starting at index 1 of row when using writerow at python

Tags: python

i have a script to create matrix of size n and write it to csv file.
i want the matrix to have "boarders" at size of n.
my code:

```
a = []
firstRow = []
for i in range(n):
    row = []
    row.append(i+1)
    firstRow.append(i+1)
    for j in range(n):
        row.append(random.randint(x,y))
    a.append(row)

writer.writerow(firstRow)
writer.writerows(a)
```

output when using n = 3

```
1,2,3
1,74,82,68
2,87,70,72
3,68,71,74
```

i need the output to be like this:

```
  1, 2, 3
1,74,82,68
2,87,70,72
3,68,71,74
```

with blank box at the csv index 0,0.
also i need the all matrix to start at row 1 instead of 0

Comment: Why not use index? and maybe pandas for this?

Comment: What is `writer` ?Why dont you simply write an empty line and some spaces before you start the writing of data if thats what you want to have?

Comment: That's not a CSV file though. You can manually write some whitespace (write directly to the file `writer` wraps), but *why*?

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas we can get the following **valid** csv with a few lines of easy-to-understand code:

```
,1,2,3
1,91,66,70
2,82,24,79
3,57,56,73
```

Example code used:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create random numbers 0-99, 3x3
data = np.random.randint(0,100, size=(3,3))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Add 1 to index and columns
df.columns = df.columns + 1
df.index = df.index + 1

#df.to_csv('output.csv')  # Uncomment this row to write to file.
print(df.to_csv())
```

---

**And** if you insist that you want to remove the leadning `,`:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df.to_csv()[1:])
```